# Visual Studio 2013 jQuery intellisense for selector?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, javascript-intellisense

I always have a typo problem on my jQuery scripts for some mis-spelled id or class name. Is there a way I can see a list of id or class when I edit my jQuery scripts? for example, if I type $('#a , intellisense will know I want to select any id in html that starts with character a, and put those ids in the popped up list.